# Copy and Paste into new row using a Loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have the following data:

```
456436     4568     1235     152456    1564   25686    1258    1456 

456436     46568    12785    12456     1564    9466    1258    1596 

456436     4568     4235     1456      1564   25686    1258    1456
```

I need to take the last four cells of data on each row and move them below the first four.

I wrote a loop, but I'm new to VBA so I don't know how to count down, so it just produces an endless loop.
    Dim i As Long

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("T2").Value
  Range("T2:AE2").Copy Destination:=Range("G3")
Next i
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you always have 8 columns or does it change some times?  As in do your last 4 values you need to copy down to a new row change columns some times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Sub S0()
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row * 2 Step 2
        Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
        Cells(i, 5).Resize(, 4).Cut Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```